# Solving $2\sqrt {x^5}-\sqrt {x^3}=2x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been stuck on this question for like an hour.

$2\sqrt {x^5}-\sqrt {x^3}=2x-1$.

The memo doesn't explain how to do it, but it says the answers are $1$ and $1/2$. I can get $1$, just not $1/2$ ever.

Working I did: $2\sqrt {x^5}-\sqrt {x^3}=2x-1$,
$2x^{5/2} - 3x^{3/2} = 2x - 1$,
$x^{3/2}(2x-1) = 2x - 1$,
$x^{(3/2)*(2/3)} = 1^{2/3}$,
$x = 1$.

Comment: Hint:  factor out $x^{3/2}$ on the left.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Please include the work you did to get the answer of $1$. This will help answerers avoid duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand. Also, it may be possible to point out a simple flaw in your logic. (Include your work in the body of the question. Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) ... Good luck!

Comment: You do have $2x^2\sqrt x-x\sqrt x=x(2x-1)\sqrt x=2x-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain $x = \frac{1}{2}$ by considering the case when $2x-1=0$, since you only considered the case when it is not zero, before simplifying
$$x^{\frac{3}{2}}(2x-1) = 2x-1$$
Which allows you to obtain
$$2x-1 = 0$$
$$\implies x =\frac{1}{2}$$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Omg thank you ; - ; I can't believe that went over my head